# installing node.js v0.8.1 via nvm fails

Tags: node.js, gcc

While installing node 0.8.1 via nvm (newest from git) I get an error, that doesn't make any sense for me;

```
CXX(target) /home/ubuntu/.nvm/src/node-v0.8.1/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/checks.o
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[1]: *** [/home/ubuntu/.nvm/src/node-    v0.8.1/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/api.o] Error 4
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/.nvm/src/node-v0.8.1/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
nvm: install v0.8.1 failed!
```

all previous installs with 0.6.18 were successful. Python is forced to python2 and libssl-dev is the newest on a ubuntu11.10. Does anybody have any advice? Thank you

Comment: Just a guess: OOM Killer? Check `dmesg` or `/var/log/kern*` for log entries around the time of the failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [created a swapfile](http://digitizor.com/2011/02/06/create-swap-file-ubuntu-linux/) on my ec2 instance and voilà, compilation worked. Thanks Alan Curry for the memory hint. Was surprised that there wasn't any swap to start with..